# How to Force a Sorting in a SWT Table w/ Table Viewer

Tags: eclipse, sorting, swt, jface

I want to sort, only for the first time, a SWT Table column.
I have a Table with their TableViewer and I want to Sort programmaticaly after or before setInput Method.

The columns are dynamically generated, and the last ones is an average column.
Is there any way of Sorting by program?

I'm using only this line of code:

```
        columnPromEcr = new TableColumn(table, SWT.RIGHT);      
        columnPromEcr.setText("Prom. ECR");
        columnPromEcr.pack();
        columnPromEcr.setResizable(true);
        this.table.setSortColumn(columnPromEcr);
```

After setInput method I call:

```
// refresh table
tableViewer.refresh();
table.setRedraw(true);
```

Do I need a class ViewerSorter?

I don't need user intervention, my data came unordered, and after creating a dynamic column I want the program to order the table with that info, numeric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ViewerSorter` if you only want to sort items before they are displayed. Use [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a ViewerSorter, it will keep the TableViewer in order all the time.

Comment: Can I use the viewerSorter only to apply to one column ? I think I have an issue with the last column (AVG) because is not an attribute of the Object (e1 and e2) that ViewerSorter recieves as parameter.

Comment: It handles only the elements of the viewer, so it's not specific to columns. You would need to get the AVG by other means if you needed it, like either calculate it in the ViewerSorter or store it in a HashSet.

Comment: It work, unfortunatelly I have to replicate logic in LabelProvider, so there is access to hibernate twice :( . I would love if the data in memory could be sorted.

Comment: I would use a HashSet then and store the data since it's expensive to calculate. The ViewerSorter's comparison method will be called frequently, so going to Hibernate each time will be terrible.

Comment: Can you consider accepting this answer if it meets your needs?

Answer (score 0):

If u want the default behavior for sorting(integer,string simple comparison) you can just set the sorter:

```
viewer.setSorter(new ViewerSorter());
```

and the viewer will be sorted all the time (e.g. after deletions,additions of data)